# Advanced Poker Calculator

Tags: poker-tools

Does anyone know of an advanced poker calculator for Windows?
Or for Universal Windows Platform (runs on Windows and smart phone)?

I found this for Mac [Poker Cruncher](http://www.pokercruncher.com/).  I am looking for a tool exactly like that but for Windows.  I know you can use tools to host a Mac application in Windows.  I am looking for a native Windows application.

Not talking about basic statistics on you versus a known hand or random hand.  A tool where you can put in a range for your opponent and get an equity.

Turns out there is Equilab and Flopzilla.  Toby answered in Chat.

I decided to write one.  Will not have the features of Flopzilla but I want to write a phone application and this seems like good application for practice.  Clearly it is not done.

[image]

Comment: I don't know but you are a programmer and a person with specific needs. What restricts you from programming a command line like that in an easy language like ruby or python? It is an interesting project to work on IMHO.

Comment: Have my upvote. If you find a tool or are you willing to code and share, it will be of a great value to the community.

Comment: Either of you guys fancy coding a hand converter for this site? Ps. Not hijacking, we can/should continue in chat room ;) Pps. I'm not a programmer otherwise I'd do it.

Comment: @TobyBooth I am a programmer but I don't know what you mean by hand converter or for this site.  If you mean convert 5 cards to a named hand that is easy - will post as a question and answer.  Do you mean like a plug in that would run on the site?  No where else in SE do they have something like that.

Comment: Then my sincere wish of good luck to you :). I prefer using Python but it is a matter of taste.

Comment: lets go to chat room :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toby Booth answered in chat

[Equilab](https://www.pokerstrategy.com/poker-software-tools/equilab-holdem/) and [Flopzilla](http://www.flopzilla.com/)

Answer (score 0):

[Premium Poker Tools](https://premiumpokertools.com/) is another option (founder here). It's a web app, so it works anywhere you have a web browser.

Answer (score 0):

[Pokerstove](https://github.com/andrewprock/pokerstove) has been one of the oldest and most stable tool when it comes to calculating equity against a range of hand. They have opensource C++ lib which is (one of ?) the fastest poker hand evaluator available in opensource.

In terms of mobile-compatible tool, all I can think of is web-based, and as such [Propokertools](http://www.propokertools.com/) stands as a reference for being able to support many variants and advanced features such as graphing etc.